# Как сериализовать Dictionary<string, object>?

Tags: c#, xml, serialize, словари

Имеется многоуровневый словарь Dictionary<string, object>, где значением опять-же может быть многоуровневый словарь Dictionary<string, object>. Каким образом можно преобразовать его в XML?

На просторах интернета [был найден класс SerializableDictionary](https://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/444961), но он работает только с одноуровневыми словарями:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class SerializableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, IXmlSerializable {

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema() {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader) {

        XmlSerializer keySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TKey));
        XmlSerializer valueSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TValue));

        bool wasEmpty = reader.IsEmptyElement;
        reader.Read();

        if (wasEmpty)
            return;

        while (reader.NodeType != System.Xml.XmlNodeType.EndElement) {
            reader.ReadStartElement("item");

            reader.ReadStartElement("key");
            TKey key = (TKey)keySerializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.ReadEndElement();

            reader.ReadStartElement("value");
            TValue value = (TValue)valueSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.ReadEndElement();

            this.Add(key, value);

            reader.ReadEndElement();
            reader.MoveToContent();
        }
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer) {

        XmlSerializer keySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TKey));
        XmlSerializer valueSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TValue));

        foreach (TKey key in this.Keys) {
            writer.WriteStartElement("item");

            writer.WriteStartElement("key");
            keySerializer.Serialize(writer, key);
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteStartElement("value");
            TValue value = this[key];
            valueSerializer.Serialize(writer, value);
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
}

public static string Serialize(SerializableDictionary<string, object> data) {
    using(StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()) {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializableDictionary<string, object>));
        ser.Serialize(sw, data);
        return sw.ToString();
    }
}

Serialize(new SerializableDictionary<string, object>() {
    { "Node 1", "Node 1 value" },
    { "Node 2", true },
    { "Node 3", 5}
});

//<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
//<dictionary>
//  <item>
//    <key>
//      <string>Node 1</string>
//    </key>
//    <value>
//      <anyType xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" d4p1:type="q1:string" xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Node 1 value</anyType>
//    </value>
//  </item>
//  <item>
//    <key>
//      <string>Node 2</string>
//    </key>
//    <value>
//      <anyType xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" d4p1:type="q1:boolean" xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">true</anyType>
//    </value>
//  </item>
//  <item>
//    <key>
//      <string>Node 3</string>
//    </key>
//    <value>
//      <anyType xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" d4p1:type="q1:int" xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">5</anyType>
//    </value>
//  </item>
//</dictionary>

Serialize(new SerializableDictionary<string, object>() {
    { "Node 1", "Node 1 value" },
    { "Node 2", true },
    { "Node 3", new int[]{1,2,3}}
});

// System.InvalidOperationException: The type System.Int32[] may not be used in this context.
// System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document.
//                                   method WriteXml valueSerializer.Serialize(writer, value);
```

В идеале хотелось бы иметь структуру XML, где имя узла соответствует имени элемента. Например:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Node1>Node 1 value</Node1>
<Node2>true</Node2>
<Node3>
  <Item>1</Item>
  <Item>2</Item>
  <Item>3</Item>
</Node3>
```

Поиграться с кодом можно [здесь](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qlDjda).

Comment: А какую структуру XML вы в итоге получить хотите? И как вы пробовали? Да и вообще, откуда такой словарь взялся? Может это не словарь вовсе, а некий объект был?

Comment: @Андрей Необходимо получить такую-же структуру, как и у словаря. Словарь такой взялся после парсинга Excel файла пользователя.

Comment: Не понятно, в Excel вроде таблица двумерная, откуда многоуровневый словарь?

Comment: Вызывать рекурсивно для вложенных словарей?

Comment: А какие объекты могут быть значениями _кроме_ словарей?

Comment: @VladD Значения могут быть примитивами, строками, DateTime и массивами.

Comment: _где имя узла соответствует имени элемента_ - в общем случае это невозможно: ключ в словаре может быть "Node 1", а имя элемента XML не может содержать пробелы.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov вполне допустимо обрабатывать имя узла в WriteXml. Не это проблема...